# Invalid literal for int() base 10 - Program won't accept input

Tags: python, list, variables, int

My code has started giving me an error when I try to use it. I need it to take input, split the numbers from a user apart, determine the average and then print the average. That all worked previously, but something has changed and now it no longer accepts the input, and gives me the error message in the title. Here's my code:

```
class1 = 0
class2 = 0
class3 = 0
class4 = 0
class5 = 0

def findAverage():
    allClasses = class1 + class2 + class3 + class4 + class5
    finalAverage = allClasses / 5
    return finalAverage


grades = int(input("Enter the grades from your five classes, seperated by a space."))

grades_list = grades.split(' ')

class1, class2, class3, class4, class5 = grades_list

findAverage()

if findAverage() >= 80:
print("Congratulations, you are on the honor roll. Your average is", findAverage)
```

Comment: For instance `'1 2 3 4 5'` is indeed an invalid integer. What were your expectations?

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
grades = int(input("Enter the grades from your five classes, seperated by a space."))
```

you are passing the `int` function a string that I would guess typically contains a series of integers *separated by a space*.  That would not be a string that `int` is capable of parsing into an integer.  You probably want this instead:

```
grades = raw_input("Enter the grades from your five classes, seperated by a space.")

grades_list = [int(grade) for grade in grades.split(' ')]

class1, class2, class3, class4, class5 = grades_list
```

You have to apply the `int` function individually to the substrings that only contain an integer.

Comment: In python2.7 input() won't work with an input string that has spaces(full disclosure I'm using python3 at the moment so maybe it's different there). In that case instead of grades=input("blah") you should use something like grades=raw_input("blah").

Comment: You should be using `raw_input` in nearly every case in Python 2.x; there's a reason it was removed (aside from just allowing `raw_input` to be renamed as `input`) from Python 3.